# How can I search for a calculated field in Laravel, a field that does not exist in the table in the DataTable?

Tags: javascript, sql, laravel, datatable

I have a field in this table, which is a calculated field that is not in the table, and I want to search for a value inside it using the data table.

[image: datatable]

Other fields I used this code, but when I use the same method for orders_count, it appears that the field does not exist

```php
$data = Visit::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'visits.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('customers', 'visits.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->leftJoin('orders', 'visits.id', '=', 'orders.visit_id')
    ->select(
        'visits.id as visit_id',
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%b-%Y") as visit_date'),
        'users.email as email',
        'customers.name as customer_name',
        DB::raw('count(orders.id) as orders_count')
    )
    ->groupBy('visits.id')
    ->skip($start)
    ->take($rowperpage);

$totalRecords = Visit::select('count(*) as allcount')->count();
$totalRecordswithFilter = Visit::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'visits.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('customers', 'visits.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->leftJoin('orders', 'visits.id', '=', 'orders.visit_id')
    ->select('count(*) as allcount');

foreach ($columnName_arr as $col) {
    if ($col['search']['value'] != '') {
        $searchValue = $col['search']['value'];
        $searchColumn= $col['data'];
    }

    if ($searchColumn != null) {
        if ($searchColumn == 'visit_id') {
            $totalRecordswithFilter->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('visits.id', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });

            $data->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('visits.id', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });
        }

        if ($searchColumn == 'visit_date') {
            $totalRecordswithFilter->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('visits.created_at', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });

            $data->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('visits.created_at', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });
        }

        if ($searchColumn=='email') {
            $totalRecordswithFilter->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('users.email', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });

            $data->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('users.email', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });
        }

        if ($searchColumn == 'customer_name') {
            $totalRecordswithFilter->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('customers.name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });

            $data->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('customers.name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });
        }

////////////////////////////Here is my question?????????????????////////////////////////////
        if ($searchColumn == 'orders_count') {
            $totalRecordswithFilter->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('orders_count', 'like', '%' . $searchValue . '%');
            });

            $data->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('orders_count', 'like', '%' . $searchValue . '%');
            });
        }

        if ($searchColumn=='status') {
            $totalRecordswithFilter->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('orders.status', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });

            $data->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('orders.status', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            });
        }
    } else {
        $totalRecordswithFilter->where(function($query) use ($searchValue) {
            return $query->where('visits.id', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
                ->orWhere('visits.created_at', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
                ->orWhere('users.email', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
                // ->orWhere('orders.id', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
                // ->orWhere('orders.status', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
                ->orWhere('customers.name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
        });
```

so,How can I search for a field orders_count that does not exist in the table in  laravel in datatable

Comment: your field `orders_count` exists on `$data`, but not on `$totalRecordswithFilter`

Answer (score 0):

```php
$data = DB::query()->from(Visit::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'visits.user_id')
   ->leftJoin('customers', 'visits.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
   ->leftJoin('orders', 'visits.id', '=', 'orders.visit_id')
   ->select(
      'visits.id as visit_id',
      DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%b-%Y") as visit_date'),
      'users.email as email',
      'customers.name as customer_name',
      DB::raw('count(orders.id) as orders_count')
   )
   ->groupBy('visits.id'), 'visits');
   
$totalRecords = Visit::query()->count();

// apply your filtering here
...

// count filtered records after filtering, no need to keep two queries
$totalRecordswithFilter = $data->count();

// apply pagination after counting filtered records
$data->skip($start)->take($rowperpage);
```

Comment: how can I apply the filtering ?This is my main question